# Error fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am implementing a research product of PDO and came across the following problem: 
when the sql query returns too many results, the process is stopped (white screen) after running the fetchAll (PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC).

-) The query was basically `SELECT * FROM product WHERE ....` (returns 3000)

After a few tries changing the query to:

-) `SELECT id, name FROM product WHERE ....`

The research work in all cases again.

Just to clarify the query was always correct because the execute () method returned true. 
The products table has about 60 columns including some kind of text that allow HTML content.

I do not have much experience with PDO, unable to resolve the emergency problem but would like to know what was the reason of the problem.

Doubt:

Are there any limitations as to this PDO? Maybe PHP to transform into array? WORKAROUND error? 
 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: `fetchAll()` pulls ALL the records from your query and dumps the lot into memory all at once I believe... now, using `SELECT * ... ` means you're pulling all 60 columns out per record (and is slightly less efficient on the SQL server anyway than providing the names of the columns as the server has to find out what they are first). If you're only specifying 2 columns to return, you'll be dumping a LOT less data into memory of course - odds are, PHP was running out of allowed allocatable memory when using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT field1,field2 from db'); 
setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Just call only the fields you need so it execute fast.

If using `SELECT * FROM....` means it get all columns.... so it takes more time to execute your query.